# How to totally overwrite the version of spring boot starter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security, spring-boot-starter

The spring boot version in my parent module is v2.1.17.RELEASE

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.17.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then I introduced spring-boot-starter-security in the sub-module, and the specified version is 2.4.4, which overwrites the version in the parent module (v2.1.17.RELEASE).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I ran the `mvn dependency:tree` command and found that the version of spring-boot-starter-security in the sub-module was indeed 2.4.4, but the version of artifactId (such as spring-aop) referenced in spring-boot-starter-security was still the version 5.1.x, which correspond to v2.1.17.RELEASE version of spring-boot-starter-security instead of the version 5.3.x which correspond to  v2.4.4 version of spring-boot-starter-security

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this example

```
<properties>
    <dependencies.version>2.1.17.RELEASE</dependencies.version>
    <security.version>2.4.4</security.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${dependencies.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>${security.version}</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. The version of spring-boot-starter-security was indeed 2.4.4，but the version of artifactId such as spring-security-web, spring-security-core is not right(5.1.x).